# Yii. Render can work as renderPartial too?

Tags: php, yii, yii2

In the past, with Yii 1, I use to load partial views with "renderPartial", if you did not use renderPartial, it loaded the "partial view" with layout. Now in Yii2, method renderPartial has been moved to the controller, BUT you also can do:

```
<?= $this->render('_form', [
    'model' => $model,
]) ?>
```

Inside another view, and it works same way as renderPartial, what kind of sorcery is this? :D. I guess in some level Yii2 checks if it is being loaded inside another view and uses renderPartial but I have not been able to find it. Anyone has found this?

I came to this question, because I was reviewing Pjax, playing with it and I saw a couple examples where the controller used return $this->render but Pjax still worked, as far as I know Pjax stops working if `<html>` tag or error has been found on the response, am I right?

Comment: Yii2 have renderPartial function, you can check at document: [http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc-2.0/yii-base-controller.html#renderPartial()-detail)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, as you see in my comment I knew that, my question is how "render" method works as renderPartial too

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All the controller and view `render()` methods are essentially using the same method, part of the `view` model. It's a key concept in DRY (don't repeat yourself) The `view` model has this method;

```
public function render($view, $params = [], $context = null)
    {
        $viewFile = $this->findViewFile($view, $context);
        return $this->renderFile($viewFile, $params, $context);
    }
```

All it does is render the view file specified by `$view`.

Now in the controller, you have two methods; `render()` and `renderPartial()`. The difference is just that in one a layout is applied, and in the other it isn't. The code looks like this;

```
public function render($view, $params = [])
{
    $content = $this->getView()->render($view, $params, $this);
    return $this->renderContent($content);
}
```

The first line in the method does two things. Firstly it gets the view object, then, by chaining, it uses the `render()` method of that view object to generate the html from that view.

The second line then passes that content on to the `renderContent()` method of the controller, which applies any layout to the content.

The code for `renderPartial()` is this;

```
public function renderPartial($view, $params = [])
{
    return $this->getView()->render($view, $params, $this);
}
```

As you can see, it's exactly the same as the `render()` method of the controller, except that it doesn't pass anything to the `renderContent()` method of the controller, it just outputs it.

As for the `pjax` part of your question, I'm guessing that as long as your `pjax` doesn't generate any substantial errors, it will work whether you are using `$controller->render()`, `$controller->renderPartial()` or `$view->render()`.

Comment: thanks for such a detailed answer. My main doubt is why calling render method inside a view works as renderPartial and not as render. I noticed the same while working with Pjax, I found an example using render, but render is suppose to return view + layout, so Pjax should not work since it should work as a redirect in presence of <html> tag.

Comment: I think you're missing the point. The `render()` method is always for the view, hence the use in a view file of `$this->render()`. `$this` refers here to the `view` object. The controller achieves the same result by first obtaining a reference to the `view` object, by using `$this->getView()`. Here, `$this` refers to the `controller` object. The view is not able to add layout, because that is correctly determined by the controller, which does this by either `$this->render()` or `$this->renderPartial()`. A view cannot add layout.

Comment: I think your confusion arises from the fact that both view and controller are using a method called `render()`. They are no the same, as they are being called in objects.

Comment: That was the missing part on my puzzle. I forgot controller is the responsible for setting the layout not the view, thanks!!